# How to store temporary data in Django?

Tags: django, web-applications, session-cookies, temporary

I'm creating an app on Django: it's a collaborative game with a chat. Every time you join a game, you choose a nickname, and it exists until you leave the game. Also chat: it is stored until the end of the game. What is the best way to store nicknames and chat?
i'm a beginner and don't understand that really... Should i use some cookies or work with sessions? Please help me it's my university project...